# Unexpected huge difference in IO speed between 2 methods

Tags: java, google-app-engine, io, google-cloud-storage

I have to retrieve a file from google cloud storage, UN-compress it and then parse it using Wire into a proto-buf object.

First I tried to do the following :

```
final GcsInputChannel inputChannel;
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream;
final GZIPInputStream compressedData;

final MusicList musicList;

logger.info("Receiving the object");
inputChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0);

final int fileSize = (int) gcsService.getMetadata(gcsFilename).getLength();
final ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(fileSize);
inputChannel.read(result);

byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.array());
compressedData = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
musicList = new Wire(MusicList.class).parseFrom(compressedData, MusicList.class);
closeQuietly(byteArrayInputStream, inputChannel, compressedData);
```

This basically first of all fetches the whole file into a byte buffer and then passes it to the UN-compressor. I thought why not amortize the time taken by passing an actual input stream to the UN-compressor.

```
final GcsInputChannel inputChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0, 1024 * 1024);
final InputStream download = Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel);
final GZIPInputStream compressedData;

final MusicList musicList;

logger.info("Receiving the object");
compressedData = new GZIPInputStream(download);
musicList = new Wire(MusicList.class).parseFrom(compressedData, MusicList.class);
closeQuietly(download, inputChannel, compressedData);
```

Surprisingly the first method runs almost 6 times faster than the second.
Clarity on this issue is much appreciated.

> -----EDIT-----

The file size is never more than a mega byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering is the key here.
Decorating a the default inputstream, returned by Channels.newInputStream with a buffered inputstream results in by far the fastest way to do the job.

Here is the final code

```
final GcsInputChannel inputChannel;
final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
final GZIPInputStream compressedData;
final InputStream inputStream;

final MusicList musicList;

logger.info("Receiving the object");
try {

    inputChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0);
    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(inputChannel));
    compressedData = new GZIPInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
    musicList = new Wire(MusicList.class).parseFrom(compressedData, MusicList.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return Collections.emptyList(); //fail
}
```

closeQuietly(bufferedInputStream, inputChannel, compressedData, inputStream);

From what I understand the default input stream lacks an efficient skip method and also is un-buffered which leads to extremely slow decompression.